# Merge CSV Files in Powershell traverse subfolders - archiving & deleting old files use folder name for Target-CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to merge many CSV-files into one (a few hundred files) removing the header row of the added CSVs.

As the files sit in several subfolders I need to start from the root traversing all the subfolders and process all CSVs in there. Before merging I want to archive them with zip deleting old CSVs. The new merged  CSV-file and the zip-archive should be named like their parent folder.

In case the Script is started again for the same folder none of already processed files should be damaged or removed accidentally.

I am not a Powershell guy so I have been copying pasting from several resources in the web and came up with the following solution (Sorry don't remember the resources feel free to put references in the comment if you know).

This patch-work code does the job but it doesn't feel very bulletproof. For now it is processing the CSV files in the subfolders only. Processing the files within the given `$targDir` as well would also be nice.

I am wondering if it could be more compact. Suggestions for improvement are appreciated.

```
$targDir = "\\Servername\folder\";  #path

Get-ChildItem "$targDir" -Recurse -Directory |
    ForEach-Object { #walkinthrough all subfolder-paths
        
        #
        Set-Location -Path $_.FullName
        
        #remove existing AllInOne.csv (targed name for a merged file) in case it has been left over from a previous execution.
        $FileName = ".\AllInOne.csv"
        if (Test-Path $FileName) {
            Remove-Item $FileName
        }

        #remove existing AllInOne.csv (targed name for archived files) in case it has been left over from a previous execution.
        $FileName = ".\AllInOne.zip"
        if (Test-Path $FileName) {
            Remove-Item $FileName
        }
        
        #compressing all csv files in the current path, temporarily named AllInOne.zip. Doing that for each file adding it to the archive (with -Update)
        # I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do that.
        dir $_.FullName | where { $_.Extension -eq ".csv"} | foreach { Compress-Archive $_.FullName -DestinationPath "AllInOne.zip" -Update}
        
        ##########################################################
        # This code is basically merging all the CSV files 
        # skipping the header of added files
        ##########################################################
        $getFirstLine = $true

        get-childItem ".\*.csv" | foreach {
        $filePath = $_

        $lines =  $lines = Get-Content $filePath  
        $linesToWrite = switch($getFirstLine) {
            $true  {$lines}
            $false {$lines | Select -Skip 1}
        }

        $getFirstLine = $false
        Add-Content ".\AllInOne.csv" $linesToWrite

        # Output file is named AllInOne.csv temporarily - this is not a requirement
        # It was simply easier for me to come up with this temp file in the first place (symptomatic for copy&paste).
        }
        #########################################################

        #deleting old csv files
        dir $_.FullName | where { $_.Extension -eq ".csv" -and $_ -notlike "AllInOne.csv"} | foreach { Remove-Item $_.FullName}

        # Temporarily rename AllinOne files with parent folder name
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter *.csv | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename.Replace("AllInOne",$_.Directory.Name) + $_.extension}
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter *.zip | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename.Replace("AllInOne",$_.Directory.Name) + $_.extension}         
    }
```

I have been executing it in the Powershell ISE. The Script is for a house keeping only, executed casually and not on a regular base - so performance doesn't matter so much.

I prefer to stick with a script that doesn't depend on additional libraries if possible (e.g. for Zip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be bulletproof, but I have seen worse cobbled together scripts. It'll definitely do the job you want it to, but here are some small changes that will make it a bit shorter and harder to break.

1. Since all your files are CSVs and all would have the same headers, you can use `Import-CSV` to compile all of the files into an array. You won't have to worry about stripping the headers or accidentally removing a row.

```
Get-ChildItem "*.csv" | Foreach-Object {
    $csvArray += Import-CSV $_
}
```

Then you can just use `Export-CSV -Path $_.FullName -NoTypeInformation` to output it all in to a new CSV file.

2. To have it check the root folder and all the subfolders, I would throw all of the lines in the main ForEach loop into a function and then call it once for the root folder and keep the existing loop for all the subfolders.

```
function CompileCompressCSV {
    param (
        [string] $Path
    )

    # Code from inside the ForEach Loop
}

# Main Script

CompileCompressCSV -Path $targetDir

Get-ChildItem -Path $targetDir -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    
    CompileCompressCSV -Path $_.FullName
}
```

3. This is more of a stylistic choice, but I would do the steps of this script in a slightly different order:

   1. Get Parent Folder Name
   2. Remove old compiled CSVs and ZIPs
   3. Compile CSVs into an array and output with Parent Folder Name
   4. ZIP together CSVs into a file with the Parent Folder Name
   5. Remove all CSV files

Personally, I'd rather name the created files properly the first time instead of having to go back and rename them unless there is absolutely no way around it. That doesn't seem the case for your situation so you should be able to create them with the right name on the first go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was helpful. Instead of using $csvArray I directly piped Import with export CSV. That was easier for me to spot inconsistencies in the CSVs.                       
     Import-CSV $_  | Export-CSV -Path ./AllInOne.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append